# How to set Random number to number of Textview with different numbers?

Tags: android, random

I am new to android developement.So,my question is, I have One `LinearLayout` and In this `LineaLayout` I have 28 `TextView` and In this `TextView` I want to display Random numbers to all `TextView` with different number which is generated by Random number.

**Currently :** `TextView` display same number to all `TextView` but I want to display different numbers to all `TextView`

**Here is the screenshot of my Layout** :
[image]

So,If anyone know then give me idea.

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: @andrei I use one random variable and that variable i have set to all textview but it is display same number to all textview.

Answer (score 2):

First Create `Arraylist` of the random number using following code snippet

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
    arrayList.add(random.nextInt(28));
}
```

then take the parent view of your table view and you can use `parenView.getChildCount()` to get the total child count of your parent.
Then you can confirm the view if it is `Textview` by using following code snippet

```
 int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parenView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = parenView.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tvChild = (TextView) view;
            tvChid.setText(arrayList.get(count) + "");
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..very simple answer